# How do I add oplog support to my Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I just used Kadira to analyze the performance of my Meteor App.

In the Trace Explorer for my login method it reports that 'You haven't added oplog support for your the Meteor app.'

and provides this link: http://goo.gl/Co1jJc

I followed the link and from what I read, Meteor by default should have oplog support turned on if you are running a version above 0.7. I am running version 0.8.2 and I Kadira is saying I haven't added oplog support for my Meteor App.

How come and how do I go about adding oplog support?

Here is some details (from Kadira) of the method that reports does not use oplog support

```
collection : users
selector: {"_id":"h5aq5trwZgkDJSKpX"}
function : observeChanges
isCursorMethod: true
fields: {"profile":1,"username":1,"emails":1}
oplog: false
noOfHandles: 1
noOfCachedDocs: 1
```

Comment: Are you running your own mongoDB server?

Comment: No I am not I am deploying to meteors test servers using meteor deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [meteor wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver):

You'll need your own mongoDB server (eg, not hosted on `meteor.com`, or on a shared mongoDB host).

Then [on mongo 2.4 only], add a new user that can access the oplog connection:

```
$ mongo -u YourExistingAdminUserName -p YourExistingAdminPassword mongo-server-1.example.com/admin
cluster:PRIMARY> db.addUser({user: "oplogger", pwd: "PasswordForOplogger", roles: [], otherDBRoles: {local: ["read"]}})
```

Then, when running your bundled Meteor app, set the MONGO_OPLOG_URL environment variable:

```
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplogger:PasswordForOplogger@mongo-server-1.example.com,mongo-server-2.example.com,mongo-server-3.example.com/local?authSource=admin
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I was under the impression oplog was enabled by default in development mode and was for meteor default app with bundles mongodb.

Comment: relevant discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/l9b1vH4_8fA

Comment: Using kadira, it shows that db is taking up 84% of the time over the past 24 hours. If oplog support is implemented for native meteor mongodb would that speed up my app greatly without doing anything to my code?

Comment: it's hard to say precisely - but I did notice a great improvement in resource usage when we went to oplog.